# AS3 ExternalInterface.call, why it doesn't work on Chrome or IE?

Tags: actionscript-3, externalinterface

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
var pageURL:String = ExternalInterface.call('window.location.href.toString');
```

The above code seems to work on Firefox, but when I try it with Chrome or IE it doesn't work (it  causes an Error and stops the swf's execution).

Any hint?

Comment: @JcFx I worked on it. At least where an answer was given... Was it the cause for my ban from asking in SO?

Comment: I don't know - I've never known anyone be banned. Best ask a moderator.

Comment: coz of your reputation points, I thought u may have the grant to do that ;) Sorry...

Comment: Why my question has been downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ExternalInterface` works in recent versions of all major browsers. The first thing you should do is wrap that call in a check to see if it is currently available:

```
if(ExternalInterface.available)
{
  ExternalInterface.call('window.location.href.toString');
}
```

The problem with Chrome and IE may be the call to window.location.href. Your best bet is to put this into a JS function, and then call that function from AS, like so:

```
//JS:

function reportHref(){
    return window.location.href.toString(); 
    // I'm not sure this is good cross-browser JS. 
    // If it isn't, you can at least test it directly in the browser
    // and get a javascript error that you can work on.
}

//AS:
var result:String = "";
if(ExternalInterface.available)
{
    result = ExternalInterface.call("reportHref");
}
else
{
    result = "External Interface unavailable";
}
trace(result);
```

Also, make sure the function you are trying to call is already present in the DOM before you try to call it - if you add your SWF before you add the script, and make the call to `ExternalInterface` immediately, then it will fail because `reportHref` doesn't exist yet.

And, finally, it's possible that a call from within the SWF to the `window.location` object might fail due to sandboxing, which won't be the case if you make the call from a JS funciton in the page.

The docs on `ExternalInterface` are pretty comprehensive, with good examples:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Comment: What you described is exactly what I did. But when the swf is running under Chrome or IE seems to stop its execution right before the line: ExternalInterface.call("reportHref") or ExternalInterface.call("window.location.href.toString")

I'm embedding the swf file using swobject, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you installed the flash debugger players for Chrome and IE? (http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html)  You should get some kind of error if it's not working. Also, see the example here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb1.html - you may need to run through the checks to determine when JS and AS are ready for each other, as described in this article, to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Also, both in JS and AS, you could wrap your calls in `try{} catch{}` blocks and trace the error to find out what you've done wrong.

Comment: In firefox everything runs fine. I need to figure out how to debug flash with chrome and understand what's the blocking error...

Comment: Install the debugger flash player from that url. And also F12 and check the console. Between those, you should be able to get either the AS or JS errors.

Comment: well i installed both :
Download the Windows Flash Player 11.4 ActiveX control content debugger (for IE) (EXE, 9.75MB)
Download the Windows Flash Player 11.4 Plugin content debugger (for Netscape-compatible browsers) (EXE, 10.36MB)

but still have not flash traces in Chrome Console... uhmmmm

Comment: Flash won't trace in the Chrome console. If you have Flash Develop you can read traces in the Log Viewer. Otherwise you'll have to find the log manually.

Comment: I think I found the point: the trouble stands in a security violation 
SecurityError: Error #2060
That's because there's a domain that serves the SWF, but the page hosting the swf is under another domain name. I want the swf to get the current location so It will know if the end user is authorized to display it....

Comment: Heh. You might have mentioned that earlier. Yes, cross-domain calls will be blocked. See here for a good introduction as to how to work around this: http://www.kevinmusselman.com/2009/03/cross-domain-scripting-using-flash/  I've got to do some work now, so good luck....

Comment: Solved, just need to pass param to swfobject calling the remote swf:
params.allowscriptaccess = "always";

Comment: It's still returning undefined for me, despite everything being set up correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Not Working in IE9

```
if(ExternalInterface.available)
{
  ExternalInterface.call('window.location.href.toString');
}
```

works everywhere

```
if(ExternalInterface.available)
{
  ExternalInterface.call('document.location.href.toString');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice hint but actually that was not the point of interest. As I commented above the problem was solved.